# Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment

Tags: netbeans, deployment, webserver, war, wildfly-8

I am trying to deploy `LBatch.war` on wildfly-8 by putting the war file in the deployment folder of the server, then in Netbeans I start the server and ends up the following exceptions.

```
14:39:53,810 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-10) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."LBatch.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."LBatch.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "LBatch.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS015599: Apache CXF library (cxf-bundle-2.6.6.jar) detected in ws endpoint deployment; either provide a proper deployment replacing embedded libraries with container module dependencies or disable the webservices subsystem for the current deployment adding a proper jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor to it. The former approach is recommended, as the latter approach causes most of the webservices Java EE and any JBossWS specific functionality to be disabled.
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.WSLibraryFilterProcessor.deploy(WSLibraryFilterProcessor.java:71)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    ... 5 more

14:39:53,815 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "LBatch.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"LBatch.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"LBatch.war\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"LBatch.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS015599: Apache CXF library (cxf-bundle-2.6.6.jar) detected in ws endpoint deployment; either provide a proper deployment replacing embedded libraries with container module dependencies or disable the webservices subsystem for the current deployment adding a proper jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor to it. The former approach is recommended, as the latter approach causes most of the webservices Java EE and any JBossWS specific functionality to be disabled."}}
14:39:53,856 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS018559: Deployed "LBatch.war" (runtime-name : "LBatch.war")
14:39:53,858 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."LBatch.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."LBatch.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "LBatch.war"

14:39:53,891 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
14:39:53,891 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
14:39:53,892 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.0.0.Final "WildFly" started (with errors) in 5084ms - Started 218 of 267 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 89 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
14:39:54,233 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment LBatch.war (runtime-name: LBatch.war) in 146ms
14:39:54,287 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "LBatch.war" (runtime-name: "LBatch.war")
14:39:54,287 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."LBatch.war".PARSE
```

Comment: See my replies at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162595/wsdl-based-webservices-on-wildfly/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Wildfly is not happy if you add CXF dependencies to your project.

It is complaining about `cxf-bundle-2.6.6.jar`.

Make sure your project doesn't include that JAR. If you are using Maven check the Dependency Hierarchy because even if you are not including it directly, maybe other projects you are using are including it.

I don't know exactly why Wildfly complains about that. Probably it already has its own set of dependencies and it doesn't need you to insert yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same issue at [WSDL based webservices on Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162595/wsdl-based-webservices-on-wildfly/) , which I just replied with references to the JBossWS documentation explaining what to do (that is, define JBoss Module dependencies and avoid bundling CXF in the deployment).